# How to fix syntax error of ";" expected but "identifier USER" found for Pascal?

Tags: syntax-error, pascal

I'm quite new to Pascal, although it's outdated, my teacher is currently having us learn it since it is the building block of Pseudocode. However, we've only made one attempt in practicing the program along with an example today. I tried creating a practice of the assignment, however, I get the error:
"Compiling main.pas
main.pas(1,15) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier USER" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode"
My code is as listed below, thank you in advance for any guidance given!

```
    Program Hello User(input,output);
     
    var
         StudentName:string;
         Age:integer;
         Hobby:string;
     begin{Main}
         writeln('Enter your name.');
         readln(StudentName);
         writeln(`Hello,`, StudentName ',nice to meet you.');
         writeln('What is your favorite hobby?');
         readln(Hobby);
         writeln('Nice to hear your hobby is ',Hobby);
         writeln('What is your age?');
         readln(Age);
         writeln(Age,' is my lucky number!');
    end.{main}
```

To print the following program and variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There shouldn't be a space in your Program names.  ```Hello User(input,output);``` isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! I've ran the program again, however, I am still having trouble since I now get the error:  Syntax error, ")" expected but "const string" found. Any idea why?

Comment: It's been some time since I last looked at pascal code, but I'm not entirely sure ```(input,output);``` is valid.   What is the purpose of ```(input, output);```?

Comment: Please mention the line the issue is reported in.

Comment: @ewokx Compare [Program Parameter in Pascal](/q/74253072).

Answer (score 3):

You fix your errors by assuming the role of the processor (the compiler) and then process your code bit by bit.

1. Token `Program`.
   “Uh-huh! I *know* the word `program`.
   Here comes a `program` source code file!”
2. Space character.
   That is a token separator.
   “I am ready to ‘eat’ the next token.”
3. Token `Hello`.
   “Wow, that’s a nice name for a beginner’s program!”
4. Space character.
   “Good, now we’ve settled that.”
5. Token `User`.
   “Hey, wait a minute.
   What’s that?” ↯

Evidently this requires a comprehensive understanding of the programming language.
Quite many programming languages, however, do not permit spaces within identifiers.
Thus `Hello User` must read `HelloUser` (the space removed) to become *one* identifier.
After `program` comes *one* identifier, not two.

```pascal
         writeln(`Hello,`, StudentName ',nice to meet you.');
```

Another aid, if you have eyesight with sufficient color perception, is syntax highlighting.
This will allow you to spot that a backtick (the character that surrounds `Hello,`) is not an acceptable string delimiter.
You will need to replace it.
But otherwise you proceed just as above:

1. Token `writeln`.
   “That’s an identifier.
   And I *know* something that goes by the name `writeln`, a procedure to be more precise.”
2. Token `(`.
   “Opening parentheses means a parameter list.
   And the `writeln` procedure does accept parameters.
   Wonderful.”
3. Token `'Hello,'`.
   “That’s a string I will pass to `writeln`.
   And `writeln` does accept strings as a first parameter.
   Splendid.”
4. Token `,`.
   “Alright.
   We’re still processing a parameter list and Jada wants to give us another parameter!
   `WriteLn` does also accept two parameters, so let’s see what the second parameter will be.”
5. Token separator  .
   “Well, it wasn’t necessary, since the comma already separates parameters, but it’s nice anyways!”
6. Token `StudentName`.
   “Here is an identifier.
   Do I know this one?
   Yes, `StudentName` identifies a `string` variable.
   And `writeLn` accepts a string variable as second parameter.”
7. Space character.
   “OK. It’s not invalid.”
8. Token `',nice to meet you.'`.
   “This can’t be right.
   I am currently processing the second parameter.
   So either

   - a token separator,
   - a plus `+` (for string concatenation in Extended Pascal),
   - a colon `:` (if you were to write something like `StudentName:20`),
   - a comma `,` (for another parameter value),
   - or a closing parentheses `)` are acceptable

   but *not* a string literal (`',nice to meet you.'`).
   Switch to complaining mode
   `Syntax error, ")" expected but "const string" found.`”

> […] Pascal, although it's outdated, […]

On the contrary.
Pascal is alive and displays continuous enhancements, in the year 2023 and beyond.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your response, it helped me understand Pascal and gave me a new perspective I should be going into when programming! A few bits went over my head since I've only been recently introduced to Pascal, but I'm really grateful for the response!

Comment: I’m glad to be of assistance, yet I couldn’t help but notice you have *un*-accepted my answer the next day. Is there any way I could improve my answer rendering it acceptable again?