# How do I resolve syntax error, ";" expected but "IF" found?

Tags: pascal

The following is my code displayed below, however, I seem to be having trouble getting my second if statement running. How do I resolve this?

```
Program HelloUser(input,output);
var
  UserName:string;
  Hobby:string;
  Age:integer;
Begin{main}
  Writeln('Hello user, please input your name.');
  Readln(UserName);
  Writeln('Nice to meeet you, ',UserName,'. Lets get to know each other better. What is your favorite hobby?');
  Readln(Hobby);
  Writeln('Nice one! ',Hobby,' is my favorite hobby too! How old are you, ',UserName,'?');
  Readln(Age);
If Age > 16 then
Begin {If}
  Writeln(Age,' is my favorite number, what a coincidence! I think we''ll be able to get along well in the future, ',UserName,'.');
End {If}
Else
Begin {Else}
  Writeln('Wow, you''re quite young to be trekking the Internet, why not enter this domain when you''re a bit older. In the meantime, exercise those bones of yours outside!');
End {Else}
If Age = 16 then
Begin {If}
  Writeln('Wow! What a coincidence,',Age,' is my favorite number and',Age,' is the age of my creator! I think we''ll be  able to get along well in the future, I look forward to interacting with you again!');
End {If}
End.{Main}
```

Depending on the user's input, 3 different outcomes should occur based on the age variable.

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is and exactly where it is located. Did you read the words in the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix syntax error of ";" expected but "identifier USER" found for Pascal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159683/how-to-fix-syntax-error-of-expected-but-identifier-user-found-for-pascal)

Answer (score 1):

As is it is clear in the error message, the compiler is expecting `;` but `if` is found.

```pascal
Begin {Else}
    Writeln('Wow, you''re quite young to be trekking the Internet, why not enter this domain when you''re a bit older. In the meantime, exercise those bones of yours outside!');
  End; {Else} // Add ; here
If Age = 16 then
```